# Ambulence-like sound when Thinkpad T400's battery is running out of power

Tags: bios, power, thinkpad

When my Thinkpad T400 is on its battery and its battery running out of power, there is ambulence-like sound. I wonder how to eliminate the annoying sound? Is there a setting in BIOS? My OS is Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks!

Comment: I've had the same problem, so you're not alone. I wonder whether it's because the computer I have is a refurbished laptop. I haven't tried it yet, but this post might help you: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/E320-how-to-disable-the-quot-low-battery-quot-beep/td-p/795661

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I deal with T400 laptops pretty frequently and I've never heard an "ambulance sound".  If I were to take a guess, someone is messing with you and has set your alert to be something annoying instead of the standard beep that I've heard from that laptop.

Comment: (1) How can I check and set the sound when battery power is running low? (2) It is very loud. It used to be just one or two beeps. No one other than me has used the laptop. I did change BIOS setting to eliminate the beep when  plug-in and out of wall power a while ago. But that shouldn't change the lower battery power sound, does it?